# Is there an omission of the word "why" in this sentence and if yes, what is the reason for it?

Tags: spoken-english, informal-language

The following context is from the movie "Serpico"

"Person 1: We'll take it from here, kid.
You don't have to hang around.

Person 2:What are you talking about?
That's my collar.

Person 1:We take the collar.
**A collar like this, don't look good,
a patrolman takes it.**

Person 2:Wait a minute.
I don't care how it looks.
Now, I did the work. I broke my ass
on this. It's my collar."

Is this just bad English? He says don't look good after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not 'bad' English, just casual informal conversation among New York police officers. Local informal talk can omit prepositions, conjunctions, etc, and use non-standard verb tenses. In more formal English it might look like this:

> A collar (arrest) like this **doesn't** look good **if** a patrolman takes it.

Comment: Nitpick: I'd "translate" into "With a collar like this, it doesn't look good if a patrolman takes it."  That is, I think it's not the collar that looks bad, but the situation surrounding the collar.